# "Could": past and conditional question

Tags: conditionals, simple-past, could

I have a doubt about the use of *could*. I know that *could* is the past simple of *can*, and is also used in conditional constructions.

How native speakers distinguish one usage from the other in everyday speech?

Example:

> John: I will need somebody over fifty to swim tomorrow. Sadly, my
>   grandfathers never learned to swim.
>
> Ben: Oh. My grandma could swim.

Is Ben talking about the past? Or is he offering his grandma for tomorrow?

There is some tip, adverb or something to talk more specifically?

Comment: I've tidied, and adjusted the example slightly. It is not clear which reading is intended here, but it would be a little scatty of Ben to intend the anecdotal reading when John is obviously looking for a solution. Often, context will disambiguate more clearly.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth. I'm wondering if there is something else besides the context.

Comment: You are quite correct that this can lead to ambiguities. Most natural languages are full of potential ambiguities. It's up to context, intonation, rephrasing, and follow-up questions to relieve them.

Comment: If I were a more clever man, I would try to construct a similar conversation containing ambiguity with *nada*.

Comment: It would be so simple if one could say "would can", does it? :) Thanks @MikeGraham

Comment: You can say "would can," but that's not how it's conjugated. It's "would be able to" as in "Oh...my grandma would be able to swim."

Comment: @JuliSmz Alas, that just isn't how English works. It's so simple already, there are lots of things you can say with no real risk of ambiguity. "My grandma could participate," "My grandma learned to swim," "My grandma can swim tomorrow," "My grandma knew how," "Maybe my grandma could swim," "My grandma could swim, God rest her soul" etc.

Comment: It is ambiguous. 1) She can = She is able to. 2) She could = She was able to.  2 means "She once swam; used to swim, but not clears if she still can." In a reported sentence, it can still show the present ability. "She said that her mother could swim." Here, could occurs just because it is reported. There is also argument that CAN and COULD are separate just separate modals, and for the purpose of usage, they need not be considered present-to-past.  In requests, COULD is preferred to CAN. (continues...)

Comment: And another connotation of a sentence like "She could finish her lessons" may even be "She was able to (had the ability to) fiish..." leaving it open for us to assume if she meant, she did, or was just talking about that time's ability.

Comment: Why do you keep saying *doubt* when you instead really mean *question*? That sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Is Ben talking about the past? Or is he offering his grandma for tomorrow?

I deduce the following from your questions:

1. If Ben was talking about the past, then the sentence would accompany an earlier date, and would've changed to *Oh. My grandma could swim back in the 80s [or whenever she could swim]*.
2. To answer your second question, I've noticed that there is *could* and not *would*. Hence, the sentence remains incomplete, because there also is a *why* to answer because the *could* needs it. Now, most speakers terminate the sentence at this point, because it is *understood* that the speaker might be asking for the permission. A fully-constructed sentence would be *Oh. My grandma could swim, **if** you would/she could...*